# Posting JSON using JQuery and to set HTTP content type - 'application /json'

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, http-post

I am using jquery to post Json data to server. However when I make a post request as below,

```
    $.ajax({
                type        :   'POST'  ,
                url         :   uri,
                data        :   jsonStrJson,
                contentType :   'application/json',
                success     :   successFunction
        });
```

The http request header content type is not "application/json" even though I posting a json object.

Since it is not applcation/json, the server does not process the requset and returns 415.

Is there a way to set the header using javascript or jquery API?

Comment: `contentTYpe` -> `contentType` ?

Comment: very keen eye @JasonP, i missed it

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you very much i posted this thiniking i dint understand the Jquery API for AJAX. My bad. Thank you Jason

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: uri,       
    data: jsonStrJson,               
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
       console.log(json);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

"contentType" instead "contentTYpe" should also solve the problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also for setting http request header parameters you can try this approach:

```
$.ajax({
       type        :   'POST'  ,
       url         :   uri,
       data        :   jsonStrJson,
       headers     : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, //this line
       success     :   successFunction
        });
```