# Ajax JSON with byte array to webapi returning "No Content-Type header"

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I need to send images alongside correlated properties in a single post using WebAPI. As a test I have created a two-property object, explicitly setting Content Type. I am being returned an error:

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.

Request Data:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer); // Valid byte[] of image
var testData = {
    extension: "textExtension",
    data: array
}
```

Post object:

```
$.ajax({
        url: apiRoot + 'api/ImageTest',
        type: 'POST',
        data: testData,
        contentType: 'application/json;',
       });
```

Fiddler Headers:

> POST http://localhost:56565/api/ImageTest HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   localhost:56565 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 71556 Pragma:
>   no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Accept: */* Origin: null User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36 Content-Type:
>   application/json; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
>   en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> extension=testExtension&data%5B0%5D=137&data%5B1%5D=80&data%5B2%5D=78&data%5B3%5D=71&data%5B4%5D=13&data%5B5%5D=10&data%5B6%5D=26&data%5B7%5D=10&data%5B8%5D=0&data%5B9%5D=0&data%5B10%5D=0&data%5B11%5D=13&data%5B12%5D=73&data%5B13%5D=72&data%5B14%5D=68&data%5B15%5D=82&data%5B16%5D=0&dat........

Return:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma:
>   no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 04 May
>   2017 16:36:00 GMT Content-Length: 801
>
> {"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type
>   header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not
>   supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'SurveyImage' from content with media type
>   'application/octet-stream'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Test Model:

```
public class SurveyImage {

    public string extension { get; set; }
    public byte[] data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is being sent as application/x-www-form-url-encoded not as application/json, look at the body of your request...

Comment: Why?  contentType is explicitly set in the request and can be seen in the headers.

Comment: set `dataType: "json"` on the ajax request object. You set only a header, not the encoding type used by the ajax request.

Comment: Trying this now, but dataType is "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. " according to the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Then I'm not sure, it has been a while since I used jQuery, the only I can tell you is the encoding of the body is application/x-www-form-url-encoded as you can see it by yourself, try to stringify the object prior to sending it, may be it solves the error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21193038/215552 It may be that the Content-Type header must be exactly `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: Also, JSON does not support unescaped byte characters outside the Unicode range; you may need to escape those bytes via `\u6543`-type encoding.